# How to write a TaskT Monad Transformer to compose asynchronous computations with other effects?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers

I construct monad transformers as variants of `chain`/`of` that take an additional argument - a type directory of the outer monad:

```js
const None =
  ({runOption: null, tag: "None", [Symbol.toStringTag]: "Option"});

const Some = x =>
  ({runOption: x, tag: "Some", [Symbol.toStringTag]: "Option"});
  
const optOfT = of => x => of(Some(x));

const optChainT = ({chain, of}) => fmm => mmx =>
  chain(mx => {
    switch (mx.tag) {
      case "None": return of(None);
      case "Some": return fmm(mx.runOption);
    }
  }) (mmx);

const arrOf = x => [x];

const arrChain = fm => xs =>
  xs.reduce((acc, x) => arrPushFlat(acc) (fm(x)), []);

const arrPushFlat = xs => ys => {
  ys.forEach(x =>
    xs.push(x));

  return xs;
};

const xs = [Some("foo"), None, Some("bar")];

console.log(
  optChainT({chain: arrChain, of: arrOf})
    (s => [Some(s.toUpperCase())]) (xs)); // [Some("FOO"), None, Some("BAR")]
```

So basically a transformer is a handwritten composition of two monads, i.e. it takes two monads and returns a new composite monad, which is thus itself composable. Welcome to composable effects.

But I cannot wrap my head around monad transformers when lazyness comes on the table. What if I want to create a monad transformer for `[Task<Option<a>, Error>]`? I'd need a transformer for asynchronous tasks, i.e. a `tChainT`, but how would this operator look like?

Here is a mechanical implementation that (AFAIK) illustrates why monads are not composable in a general manner:

```
const tChainT = ({chain, of}) => fmm => mmx =>
  chain(mx =>
    tChain(fmm) (mx) // A
      ) (mmx);
```

Line `A` returns a `Task` that when run will eventually yield an `Array` of `Task`s of `Option`s and then will be passed to the given continuation. But I need the result right away.

Here is the part of my `Task` implementation that is relevant to the question:

```
const Task = k =>
  ({runTask: (res, rej) => k(res, rej), [Symbol.toStringTag]: "Task"});

const tChain = fm => mx =>
  Task((res, rej) => mx.runTask(x => fm(x).runTask(res, rej), rej));

const tOf = x => Task((res, rej) => res(x));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tChainT` function from your question doesn't work as expected because it has the wrong type.

```js
const tChainT = ({chain, of}) => fmm => mmx =>
  chain(mx =>
    tChain(fmm) (mx) // A
      ) (mmx);

// can be simplified to

const tChainT = ({ chain }) => fmm => chain(tChain(fmm));

// tChain  ::                   (a -> Task e b) -> Task e a -> Task e b
//                                                 |______|    |____|
//                                                    |          |
// chain   :: Monad    m     =>                      (a     ->   m    b) -> m        a      ->   m    b
//                    _|__                                                 _|__    __|___       _|__
//                   |    |                                               |    |  |      |     |    |
// tChainT :: Monad (Task e) => (a -> Task e b) ->                        Task e (Task e a) -> Task e b
```

The `tChainT` function from [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57242679/783743) also has the wrong type.

```js
// tChainT :: Monad m => (a -> Task e b) -> m (Task e a) -> m (Task e b)
const tChainT = ({chain, of}) => fm => mmx =>
  chain(mx =>
    of(tChain(fm) (mx))) (mmx); // ***A***
```

Notice that the return type of `fm` is `Task e b` instead of `m (Task e b)`. Thus, `tChainT` does not return a valid monadic bind function. In fact, it's impossible to create a function of the type `Monad m => (a -> m (Task e b)) -> m (Task e a) -> m (Task e b)` because `m (Task e a)` is the wrong structure of the `TaskT e` monad transformer. The correct structure is as follows.

```js
// newtype TaskT e m a = TaskT { runTaskT :: (a -> m (), b -> m ()) -> m () }
const TaskT = runTaskT => ({ [Symbol.toStringTag]: "TaskT", runTaskT });

// tChainT :: (a -> TaskT e m b) -> TaskT e m a -> TaskT e m b
const tChainT = f => m => TaskT((res, rej) =>
    m.runTaskT(x => f(x).runTaskT(res, rej), rej));

// tOfT :: a -> TaskT e m a
const tOfT = x => TaskT((res, rej) => res(x));
```

Notice that `tChainT` and `tOfT` have the same implementation as `tChain` and `tOf` respectively. This is because the underlying monad of `TaskT` comes from the resolution and rejection handlers. Hence, the continuation machinery handles it for us. After all `Task` is just [`Cont`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_transformer#The_continuation_monad_transformer) with an extra continuation for rejection.